# Conditionally rendering icons depending on the existence of certain values in an array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In an Axios request, I have a for-loop that assigns data to a data object, depending on the action type:

```
for (var i = 0; i < actions.length; i++) {
    switch (actions[i].type) {
        case vm.ACTION_TYPE_UNREAD_AUTHOR_COMMENTS:
            var authorObject = JSON.parse(actions[i].data);

            vm.actionsRequired[vm.ACTION_TYPE_UNREAD_AUTHOR_COMMENTS] = authorObject;
        break;

        case vm.ACTION_TYPE_UNREAD_EDITOR_COMMENTS:
            var editorObject = JSON.parse(actions[i].data);

            vm.actionsRequired[vm.ACTION_TYPE_UNREAD_EDITOR_COMMENTS] = editorObject;
        break;

        case vm.ACTION_TYPE_UNVERIFIED:
            var unverifiedObject = JSON.parse(actions[i].data);

            vm.actionsRequired[vm.ACTION_TYPE_UNVERIFIED] = unverifiedObject;
        break;

        case vm.ACTION_TYPE_DUPLICATES:
            var duplicatesObject = JSON.parse(actions[i].data);

            vm.actionsRequired[vm.ACTION_TYPE_DUPLICATES] = duplicatesObject;

        break;
    }
}
```

This code generates an object as such:

[image: img1]

In my template, I am trying to dynamically display icons depending on whether or not certain information exists in this object. I am starting with the `author-comments`.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- reference.article_reference_id is 1831 in this iteration -->
<span class="author-comments"
    v-if="actionsRequired[ACTION_TYPE_UNREAD_AUTHOR_COMMENTS][reference.article_reference_id]">
        <div class="tool-tip" style="display:inline">
            <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
            <span><i class="fas fa-circle"></i></span>
            <span class="tooltiptext">Unread author comments</span>
        </div>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span style="color:lightgray">|</span>&nbsp;
</span>
<span class="author-comments" v-else>
    <div class="tool-tip">
        <i class="saved fas fa-comment" style="color: #6C60C9"></i>
        <span class="tooltiptext">Has author comments</span>
    </div>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span style="color:lightgray">|</span>&nbsp;
</span>
```

Article reference ID of `1831` exists at `vm.actionsRequired[vm.ACTION_TYPE_UNREAD_AUTHOR_COMMENTS][0]`, but it is not rendering the correct icon.

I was thinking of using a combination of `v-for` and `v-if`, but that just rendered an icon for each comment that was there.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

---

Edit:

I've made the following edit to the code:

```
<!-- IF/ELSE Author comment icons -->
<div style="display:inline" v-for="(action, actionIndex) in actionsRequired[ACTION_TYPE_UNREAD_AUTHOR_COMMENTS]">
    {{ action.article_reference_id }}
    <span class="author-comments"
        v-if="action.article_reference_id == reference.article_reference_id">
            <div class="tool-tip" style="display:inline">
                <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                <span><i class="fas fa-circle"></i></span>
                <span class="tooltiptext">Unread author comments</span>
            </div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span style="color:lightgray">|</span>&nbsp;
    </span>
    <span class="author-comments" v-else>
        <div class="tool-tip">
            <i class="saved fas fa-comment" style="color: #6C60C9"></i>
            <span class="tooltiptext">Has author comments</span>
        </div>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span style="color:lightgray">|</span>&nbsp;
    </span>
</div>
```

However, it's displaying an icon for every unread comment there is.

[image: img2]

Is there any way to display the icon just the one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how bracket notation works in JavaScript...

Assuming `ACTION_TYPE_UNREAD_AUTHOR_COMMENTS` is `author-comment`, `actionsRequired[ACTION_TYPE_UNREAD_AUTHOR_COMMENTS]` would yield this array:

```
[
  { "id": 19, "article_reference_id": 1831, "user_id": 25493, "role_id": 65536, "text": "This is comment number 7" },
  { "id": 20, "article_reference_id": 3062, "user_id": 2, "role_id": 65536, "text": "This is comment number 8" },
  { "id": 30, "article_reference_id": 12889, "user_id": 25493, "role_id": 65536, "text": "fgdfgfgergfsgsfsdfsdfsdf" },
]
```

Further, if `reference.article_reference_id` were `1831`, the result would be:

```
actionsRequired[ACTION_TYPE_UNREAD_AUTHOR_COMMENTS][1831] === undefined
```

It's `undefined` because there is no property key by that name in the array above. The valid keys for that array are `0`, `1`, and `2` (corresponding to the indexes).

Perhaps that code was ultimately intended to determine whether there are any unread comments. If so, you should instead check whether the `author-comment` array were non-empty:

```
<span class="author-comments"
      v-if="actionsRequired[ACTION_TYPE_UNREAD_AUTHOR_COMMENTS].length">
```

**UPDATE:**

> However, it's displaying an icon for every unread comment there is.

The comment icon is shown for every unread comment because `<i class="fa-comment">` exists in **both** `v-if` and `v-else` blocks, effectively making the icon unconditional:

```
<span v-if="...">
  <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
</span>
<span v-else>
  <i class="saved fas fa-comment"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: I've made an edit to the original question, thank you for the direction

Comment: @MIkeK The icon always appears because it's in both `v-if` and `v-else` blocks. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: It's two different icons, but it's fine. I restructured the data object being sent back from the server, so that way I can just set data flags on the front end. Anyway, it works now, thanks for you time